# Implement SharedPreference in getview

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-adapter, android-checkbox

How can I implement `SharedPreference` in my `Adapter` class?
I want to use it for persisting `CheckBox` state. Now the `CheckBox` value unchecks itself when I change `Activity` or add a new item in the `ListView`.

```
public class listItems extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {

Activity context;
List<Items> listitems;

public listItems(Activity context, List<Items> listitems) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_items, listitems);
    this.context = context;
    this.listitems = listitems;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();


    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null, true);


    final Items items = listitems.get(position);

    final TextView tvitemname = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvitemname);

    final CheckBox simpleCheckedTextview = (CheckBox) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.cb);
    tvitemname.setText(items.getItemname());
    simpleCheckedTextview.isChecked();




    return listViewItem;
}
```

I've added my Items class. Is this looking good? I have a `TextView` that gets data from `FireBase`.

**Class:**

```
public class Items {

String itemId;
String itemname;
private boolean checked;

public Items(){

}


public Items(String itemId, String itemname, boolean checked) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
    this.itemname = itemname;
    this.checked = checked;
}




public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public String getItemname() {
    return itemname;

}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}
```

Comment: You can pass the SharedPreference object to the adapter constructor but I recommend you to read this value outside the adapter and pass a Map<ItemId, Boolean> where the Boolean value is selected or unselected.

Comment: Ok, is it possible for you to show me in my code?

Comment: Just add an additional boolean property to your `Items` class--something like `isItemChecked` then when your list is populated set the value of `simpleCheckedTextview` accordingly and change the value of `isItemChecked` when the checkbox changes.

Comment: Yes, if this Item is just a model used for view creation there is no problem to add this property directly to it.

Comment: But I need to use sharedpreference to save the values?

Comment: You can use any kind of storage you want, but this is not your previous question

Comment: Could this data be saved only in memory or do you need to save it in an external source to access over many app openings/closes?

Comment: Downvoted because the main question is the consequence for many other unresolved questions. Please clarify your doubts in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

How can I implement SharedPreference in my adapter class:

Save:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  context.getSharedPreferences("checkboxpref", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("checkbox_value", true);
editor.apply();
```

Get:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  context.getSharedPreferences("checkboxpref", 0);
final boolean getShared = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkbox_value", false);
```

Comment: Ok, I have a listview where I get data (Item) from firebase. I added a checkbox besides my textview (tvitemname). So I want this checkbox to save/hold its value till I check it again. Even if I close my app I want it to save the last value. But I don't need the checkbox value in firebase, but maybe I have to, since I use firebase for the textview item?

Comment: It depends. Do you want to persist this data related to a specific user even in different devices? If yes you should send it to firebase, otherwise just save it locally. You can use SharedPreferences, Room, Realm or any other available local storage.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are new in Android development, so I advise you to start working with `RecyclerView` instead `ListView`. [This](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-handling-checkbox-state-in-recycler-views-71b03f237022) is a good article to help you handle checkBox states on RecyclerViewAdapters.

The way adapters handles states for each item is totally different from how the Activity does. Once you scroll and the items are not visible they are destroyed and recreated again only when visible. That’s why you need to store the state of all values at least in memory with a Map or a SparseArray for example. Just follow step by step the link and it will work.

Do you want to persist this data related to a specific user even in different devices? If yes you should send it to your Firebase, otherwise just save it locally. You can use SharedPreferences, [Room](http://Room%20Persistence%20Library%20%7C%20Android%20Developers%20https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), [Realm](https://realm.io/) or any other local storage.

Comment: This is just for one device, so I don't need it to be stored in Firebase. I just thought it would be easier. I just having difficulties to implement sharedpreference in my adapter class, under getview. So that the values get saved. I manage to save the values if I do it in my MainActivity (I tested with a checkbox in my MainActivity, and that worked). But to do this in a listview that are getting data from firebase was not that easy.

Comment: Have you tried this link I sent? The way lists handle states for each item is totally different from Activity. Once you scroll and the items are not visible they are destroyed and recreated again when only when visible. That’s why you need another source with the state of all values, as a map or a sparsearray. Just follow step by step the link and it will work.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to check it out. Thank you for your help:)